# Java Convention of Getter&Setter

Tags: getter-setter

I got a question about the Java convention of using Getter & Setter.

By now I have a basic understanding of how Java works and I've written a Flappy-Bird and several other tools myself.

What I still dont understand is: Why to use Getter & Setter?

I mean: If I have a variable x and set that variable public, then everyone else working at the project can access it.
If I want to prevent that, then okay, i set it private and write a public Getter-method to allow others get the variable(but not modify it).

But if I now also write a public Setter-method, then everyone can use that Setter-method to modify the variable.

Overall I just see any sense when I only want others to read(get) my variable, but if they should also be able to modify(set) it, why not just make the variable public?

Edit: I've read about one advantage being that I can easily add one line of code in the Setter instead of in every usage of the public variable, if my Setter is supposed to do more than setting the variable, but wouldn't that again be considered as bad style?

Answer (score 0):

You should use encapsulation because it is the best way to control access to your class variables. It is not that important in small projects, but if you get that habit of writing setters & getters everywhere, it will be easier to manage larger projects, including huge APIs, where setters and getters methods do a lot more than just set the value and return it.

I think you should read more about encapsulation in the internet, it will explain you a lot more than I can.

Comment: Okay, I will. Can you give me an example of when a getter and another example of when a setter should do more than just getting/setting? I'm a bit confused by that.

Comment: Setter can update some other parameters in your class, for example. Or update the UI. Or make some database calls. It all depends on what you need.

Comment: Ah u mean like in a 2D game with x,y for player coordinates the setter always sets x & y and then calls the graphics updater.